# how to transform automatically a regular tabular into a tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, r

Consider this simple `tex` table

```
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}
mytext1 & mytext2 & value1 & value2\\
\midrule
HELLO & HELLO & 1 & 1\\
WORLD & AGAIN & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

This output is generated automatically by my R code. I would like to change the table environment to `tabularx`, so that when I use it in my `tex` code (with `input`), the tables stretches nicely to the width of the page.

My question is: what should I change in the `tex` code above to that this table becomes a regular `tabularx` table? Just replacing `tabular` by `tabularx` does not work Is there a solution that is generalizable and that I can code up?

Thanks!

Comment: It can't work if you don't specify the tabularx width (and replace at least  one of the column descriptors with the `X` column type).

Comment: thanks @Bernard. Is there a way to code that up?

Comment: Yes, the one described in the manual.

Comment: @TeXnician what do you mean? Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, some (most) LaTeX packages do really have manuals (cf. https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). Maybe you want to read some seconds.

Comment: @TeXnician I saw the manual, I dont see how to convert this table to tabularx though. That is why I am asking here. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have put an excerpt of the first manual page as answer. The usual advice would be to read that page.

Comment: I would never use tabularx for tables of data as you typically get from R (and I wrote tabularx:-) tabularx is all about _line breaking_ within cells which does not usually apply to data tables.

Comment: HI @DavidCarlisle thanks for your input. Sorry but I dont get your point exactly. Why is `tabularx` bad here? I just want something that outputs my R dataframes to `tex`, and stretches its columns nicely as well.

Comment: stretching the columns apart should be a non-aim, it just makes the table harder to read.  The point of a tabularx column is to have a `p` column like `p{5cm}` but where the length is set automatically, and within that column paragraphs of text are set to lines of 5cm length, using it to force numeric data to be in an inappropriately wide column is just misusing the environment (although a lot of people do it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your nice comment. I dont agree that it makes the data harder to read given that everybody uses it, but I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think anyone will find the second table easier to read than the first, your eye loses the association between the cells [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqN9G.png)

Comment: agreed. for a few columns stretching make no sense. but with more and more columns, stretching is actually beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the manual states (to be seen on page 1) you have to use the following syntax (and you want to use at least 1 X-type column):

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}[<pos>]{<preamble>}
```

That means, just substitute your table starter with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXrr}
```